# PIXIJS Sort and anchor(0.5) confusing

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, pixi.js

quick question !

this one contains each object on the stage including the player
every object anchor are fixed at 0.5 (center center)

and here i try to sort them on stage

```
this.YSort = []; //group of objects
this.YSort.children.sort((a, b) => { return a.y - b.y; });
```

i think the problem is probably cause object are centered cause before i swap my engine i was anchoring at 0.5, 1 (center bottom) and it was working properly.

is there a way to return something that can verify even if i'm using anchor(0.5);

Comment: But what is the problem? :) Also would be good if you add working example on codesandbox, jsfiddle or pixiplayground etc - this way you will for sure get answer much quicker.

Comment: Why is there a tag of esoteric-languages?